# Are there any slugs besides Katsuyu in the Naruto universe?

Tags: naruto

The Legendary sannin Jiraiya, Orochimaru, and Tsunade have summoning contracts with toads, snakes and slugs respectively. While Jiraiya and Orochimaru summon different toads and snakes on different occasions, Katsuyu is the only slug that Tsunade has summoned.

Later, their students, Naruto, Sasuke, and Sakura gain their summoning techniques. Naruto and Sasuke summon different toads and snakes. However, when Sakura summons a slug in Chapter 634, it is Katsuyu again.

Are there any slugs besides Katsuyu in the Naruto universe?

Answer (score 6):

As of Chapter 655, Katsuyu is the only slug to have been seen summoned using Kuchiyose no Jutsu, by Tsunade and Sakura.<sup>1</sup> The only other character known that *could* count as a slug is Saiken, also known as Rokubi (Six Tails).

[image: Saiken with Utakata]

Kishimoto has also drawn three other slugs on the cover pages of Chapter 4, Chapter 153, and Chapter 162.

[image: Chapter 4 cover]
[image: Chapter 153 cover]
[image: Chapter 162 cover]

---

<sup>1</sup> While we have seen toads at Myoboku Mountain, and the White Snake Sage at Ryuchi Cave, the Shikkotsu Forest where slugs reside has not been shown yet.